# python request post not working

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have a question about python request post. With the post, it still returns the searching page not the result page.

I have searched around, but I couldn't solve it by myself.

website: http://facilityquality.dads.state.tx.us/qrs/public/qrs.do?page=searchCity&lang=en&mode=P&dataSet=1&ctx=2630332

my code (headers are not included):

```
url_city_search='http://facilityquality.dads.state.tx.us/qrs/public/qrs.do?page=searchCity&lang=en&mode=P&dataSet=1&ctx=2630332'

data={"serviceTypeOption":"al_B","cityName":"Houston","dispatch":"citySearch"}
s = requests.Session()
providers=s.post(url_city_search,headers=headers,data=data,timeout=15, verify=True)
print providers.status_code
print providers.text
```

Answer (score 1):

@sideshowbarker answered your question quite well, but I thought it was also worth adding that `requests` will handle building the parameter string for you if you pass a dict to the optional `params` argument in your request. It's easy to get the parameters wrong when building the string yourself.

```
import requests
url_params = {
    "page": "qrsSearchResults",
    "lang": "en",
    "mode": "P",
    "dataSet": "1"
}
url_base = "http://facilityquality.dads.state.tx.us/qrs/public/qrs.do"
data = {"serviceTypeOption":"al_B", "cityName":"Houston", "dispatch":"citySearch"}
s = requests.Session()
providers = s.post(url_base, params=url_params, data=data, timeout=15, verify=True)
print providers.status_code
print providers.text
```

Comment: Good point. Actually, can’t the `data` members also being combined with the URL params? They are all just params and values too.

Comment: Yes! I wasn't sure if they were url parameters or form data, but they absolutely can (and should) be added.